# Why I get "Your card's expiration month is invalid" in Stripe

Tags: cakephp, stripe-payments

I'm trying to post a new card using Stripe HTTP API and I think Im doing right by the docs. I'm using cake's HttpSocket to make the request directly, and by the output here shown, i think is well formed. But I'm still getting the error :(.

```
Array
(
    [method] => POST
    [uri] => https://api.stripe.com/v1/customers/cus_49G6yn5Bj5tKkD/cards
    [auth] => Array
        (
            [method] => Basic
            [user] => <my-secret>
            [pass] => 
        )

    [body] => Array
        (
            [card] => Array
                (
                    [number] => 4242424242424242
                    [exp_month] => 05
                    [exp_year] => 2014
                    [name] => Card Holder
                )

        )

)
```

See the expiration month is a 2 digit number and if you look at the raw request, it's been sent as it should be: 
This is the raw request:

```
POST /v1/customers/cus_49G6yn5Bj5tKkD/cards HTTP/1.1
Host: api.stripe.com
Connection: close
User-Agent: CakePHP
Authorization: Basic <my-authorization-code>
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 109

card%5Bnumber%5D=4242424242424242&card%5Bexp_month%5D=05&card%5Bexp_year%5D=2014&card%5Bname%5D=Card+Holder
```

and this is the response:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Your card's expiration month is invalid.",
    "type": "card_error",
    "param": "exp_month",
    "code": "invalid_expiry_month"
  }
}
```

Comment: The API may be saying the date is invalid based on the number, not malformed.  I believe there is an algorithm that relates the number to the expiration date, if that check fails the expiration date is invalid.

Comment: In the examples in the API documentation, expiration month is not zero-padded. Try just removing the '0'.

Comment: @slim The first time i got the error, the number wasn't zero padded. That was when I read (sic. from the api doc) "exp_month: required
Two digit number representing the card's expiration month.". And I noticed the example too, but i realize is a "Response example", so I gather it doesn't apply to requests.

Comment: @DaveSwersky if that's the case, I've been unable to find the exact test data I need to use. In the documentation they give just the card numbers and the card type. I'll keep looking.

Answer (score 3):

All the error was because the card *is* expired as of June 2014; as @daveSwersky noted Stripe not just check for malformed data but it also checks the values.
So, the answer get to him :)

Comment: Thanks man. I just got the same error and this post really helped me :-)